# My binary search function in Python is not working

Tags: python, arrays

I am developing a Binary Search function in Python. It is not working and shows up as a nothing coming up.

I have tried to set up the logic with Pseudocode and my teacher says that it works, however they have no idea why the algorithm and function are doing what they are doing. I have skinned the fat on my Pseudocode and multiple people have been able to fix my problem.

```py
def binary_search(array,item):
    start_point = 0
    end_point = len(array)
    mid_point = int((start_point + end_point) / 2)
    array.sort()
    print(array)it
    while array[mid_point] != item:
        if array[mid_point] > item:
            start_point = mid_point
        elif array[mid_point] < item:
            end_point = mid_point
    if array[mid_point] == item:
        print(mid_point)

binary_search([0,99,2,6,4,8],7)
```

I want this function to work so that when you enter an array and a search term it shows where there is in the array (the index value)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here's a guide on how to ask questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. More specifically, what is your expected output from entering the array above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly before solving problem let's discuss binary search,

Binary Search: *Search a sorted array by repeatedly dividing the search interval in half. Begin with an interval covering the whole array. If the value of the search key is less than the item in the middle of the interval, narrow the interval to the lower half. Otherwise narrow it to the upper half.*

Here you need to change midpoint every time when while loop completes it's single loop and then you need to check if item is in lower half or upper half if it is present in lower half then you need to change end-point not start-point and if in upper half then change lower-point

And one important thing, in your while condition if element is not present then it will be in infinite loop so your while loop condition must be while(end_point > start_point) because we are changing points in each loop.

Code for reference:

```
def binary_search(array,item):
    start_point = 0
    end_point = len(array)
    array.sort()
    print(array)
    while end_point > start_point:
        mid_point = int((start_point + end_point) / 2)
        if array[mid_point] < item:
            start_point = mid_point+1
        elif array[mid_point] > item:
            end_point = mid_point-1
        elif array[mid_point] == item:
            print(mid_point)
            return
    print("ELement is not present")

binary_search([0,99,2,6,7,8],3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually doing anything with `start_point` and `end_point`.

Also, if the element at the middle is greater than the item you're looking for, wouldn't you want to move the `end_point` to the middle? Same thing goes for your elif-statement - if the element in the middle is less than the item you're looking for, you'd want to move the `start_point` to the middle.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing a good job with this pseudo code, However, it is not complete. Consider the following points:

- You need to add a condition to the `while` loop to stop if the `mid_point` becomes `zero`.
- You need also to update the value of `mid_point` at each branch of the `if` condition.
- You need to subtract `1` from the first assignment of `mid_point` since **python** is a *zero-indexed* language.

Here is a working version of the code:

```
def binary_search(array,item):
    start_point = 0
    end_point = len(array)
    mid_point = int((start_point + end_point) / 2)-1
    array.sort()
    print('array after sorting:',array)

    while mid_point < len(array) and mid_point > 0:
        if array[mid_point] == item:
            print('item found at cell:',mid_point,', Note that array index starts from zero!')
            return
        elif array[mid_point]>item:
            end_point = mid_point
            mid_point = int((start_point + end_point) / 2)
        else:
            start_point = mid_point
            mid_point = int((start_point + end_point) / 2)
    print('number not found!')
    return


binary_search([0,99,2,6,4,8,12,13,17,15],8)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is going wrong is that the `while` loop is comparing the same value of `array[mid_point]` at every iteration, thus ending into an infinite loop if the condition satisfies.

Binary Search is a recursive approach and iterates over lesser elements of the same list with every iteration until the required element's index is obtained, if it is present in the list.
Your code will work if you slice the `array` and call `binary_search` recursively passing the newer list as the argument. The `while` loop then can be replaced by a simple `if` condition.

For more reference, check [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/) and compare with your function to understand the difference. :)